# Grials clean command prevent deleting resources

Tags: grails

How to prevent the grails `clean` command, not to delete a newly added folder in `web-app` folder.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use lots of custom folders in webapp, but grails-clean doesn't delete any of mine. Plz rename the folder to some other and check again.

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange, but when you do the grails clean, grails delete the folder web-app/plugins, and any other name that doesn't happen...